# How to square integers inside an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just filtered a set of decimals and integers so that I only have a set of integers. Now I have to compute the square of those filtered integers.

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const squareList = (arr) => {

"use strict";


  const squaredIntegers = realNumberArray.filter(x => x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x));



return squaredIntegers;
};

// test your code

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: You can map over the array some_array.map(e => e * e)

Comment: And the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map over the array and do [`Math.pow(int,power)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) but multiplication is faster so do `value * value` in the `.map` function

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]; // your array
const squares = realNumberArray.filter(x => x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x)); // your filter function
const squared = squares.map(val => val*val) // map and do val*val to get an array of elements of val*val
console.log(squared) // log it
```

Your code becomes

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const squareList = (arr) => {

  "use strict";
  const squaredIntegers = realNumberArray.filter(x => x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x));
  const squared = squaredIntegers.map(val => val*val)
  return squared;
};

// test your code

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.map

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const squareList = (arr) => {
    return realNumberArray
        .filter(x => x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x))
        .map(x => x * x);
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```